# Profile on contribution page doesn't show membership custom fields

Tags: civimember, custom-fields, profile

On a very simple Drupal 10.1 + CiviCRM 5.69.2 site.

Add a custom fieldset for memberships (e.g. with a simple text field).

Include the custom field from that fieldset in a profile.

That field does not show up when that profile is included on the contribution page [I tried a few permutations of putting it in it's own profile, including in a profile which includes other contact fields that do show up, etc.]

Oddly, I thought it was showing up and now it isn't - not sure if that's due to a CiviCRM upgrade in the meantime or something else.

BUT, I was not able to reproduce this behaviour on the demo site:

https://d10-master.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2

i.e. it's working there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is that I turned on the 'on behalf of' option. When I do that on the demo site, I get this message:

> Allow individuals to contribute and / or signup for membership on
> behalf of an organization? You should move the membership related
> fields configured in 'Includes Profile (top of page)' to the 'On
> Behalf' profile for this Contribution Page

The demo site is running a few versions later, so I suspect this is a known issue that has been resolved in recent versions.

For my site, I believe that even though I turned off the on-behalf-of, there's something left behind that prevents the membership fields from being exposed.

When I add the membership fields to the on-behalf-of profile they do show up on my site, so that does appear to be the origin of the issue and sort-of-work-around.

In other words, because at some point I enabled the on-behalf-of-organization feature on the contribution page (and then disabled it later), I still have to put my custom membership fields in the on-behalf-of profile, and they don't show up otherwise.